# Link tables on Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have my Django model like this:

```
ClassA(models.Model):
    # some code

ClassB(models.Model):
    #some code
    classa = ForeignKey(ClassA)

ClassC(models.Model):
    # Some code
    classb = ForeignKey(ClassB)
```

the thing is that in the Django Admin App, it loads all the `ClassB` data, and I need to show a Select element with something like this:

```
ClassB [Value] - ClassA[Value]
```

Is that possible?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you mean by `ClassB [Value] - ClassA[Value]`. But it seems that you are looking for loading values or choices to be more appropriate dynamically for a  `SELECT` element.

To dynamic load choices in Django admin, you can supply a function to the `choices` parameter of a models.Field. For example:

```
def get_choices():
    #some code 
    return list_of_tuple

classB(models.Model):
    select = models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=get_choices)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should supply a custom [formfield_for_foreignkey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey) method in your admin class for the model that you want the drop down to show.